# In relation to General Relativity, Invariant form of Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations, covariance

I am a High school student, so am new to this topic.

Using my own understanding I want to come up with the covariant(or invariant) form of Lorentz force. But I am unable to do it.

---

**MY IDEA:**

Let $\displaystyle \vec{S} = c^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}$ be the general position vector of any point in space, then

In general: $$\displaystyle  \frac {\partial \vec{S}}{\partial \lambda} = \frac {\partial \tau}{\partial \lambda} \frac {\partial \vec{S}}{\partial \tau} $$
And, $\displaystyle \vec{U} = \frac {\partial \vec{S}}{\partial \lambda} $ as well as $\displaystyle \vec{A} = \frac {\partial \vec{U}}{\partial \lambda} $.

Hence, $\displaystyle \vec{U} = \frac {\partial \tau}{\partial \lambda} \left (\frac {\partial c^{\nu}}{\partial \tau} \partial_{\nu} + c^{\nu} \frac {\partial_{\nu}}{\partial \tau} \right )  = \frac {\partial \tau}{\partial \lambda} \left ( \partial_{\tau}c^{\mu} + c^{\nu} \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\tau} \right )  \partial_{\mu} $

OR

> $$ \displaystyle \vec{U} = \partial_{\lambda}\tau \nabla _{\tau}c^{\mu}  \partial_{\mu}$$

Hence $\displaystyle \vec{A} = \partial^{2}_{\lambda}\tau \nabla _{\tau} c^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + (\partial_{\lambda}\tau)^2 \partial_{\tau}\nabla _{\tau} c^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + (\partial_{\lambda}\tau)^2 \nabla _{\tau} c^{\mu}\partial_{\tau} \partial_{\mu}$

OR

> $$\displaystyle \vec{A} = \partial^{2}_{\lambda}\tau \nabla _{\tau}
>  c^{\mu}   \partial_{\mu} + (\partial_{\lambda}\tau)^2 \nabla _{\vec{\tau}}
>  \nabla _{\tau} c^{\mu}  \partial_{\mu} + (\partial_{\lambda}\tau)^2
>  \nabla _{\tau} c^{\mu}  \partial _{\tau} \partial_{\mu} $$

Therefore

> $$\displaystyle \vec{F} = (m\partial^{2}_{\lambda}\tau \nabla _{\tau}
>  c^{\mu} + m(\partial_{\lambda}\tau)^2 \nabla _{\vec{\tau}} \nabla 
>  _{\tau}c^{\mu} + m(\partial_{\lambda}\tau)^2 \nabla _{\tau} c^{\rho} \Gamma^{\mu}_{\rho \tau})\partial_{\mu}. $$

**#NOTE:** $m$ is the rest mass.

---

Basically, $\displaystyle \vec{S} $ is invariant, thus this should apply that $\displaystyle \vec{F} $ must be invariant. But if it is then, it would be applicable for any type of force(or may be I am wrong here).

But I have no Idea how to proceed further. I thought to compare the Lorentz Force : $\displaystyle \vec{F} = q(\vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B}) $ components. But here I do not know what would the time component be.

---

So, I want a hint to guide me in the proper direction. May be I am totally wrong in comparing the components, so please tell what other way I should use to eventually arrive on Invariant form of Lorentz force.

Comment: You're going to have difficulty doing this from scratch in four dimensions without further study in electromagnetism.  The big hint is to not work in terms of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$, but rhater the 4-potential, $(\phi, {\vec A})$, where $\phi$ is the ordinary electric potential, and $\vec A$ is the magnetic vector potential.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Ok, I will take that into consideration. Thank you very much.

Comment: So it means using $4 \text{-potential}, (\phi, \vec{A})$, I can derive an INVARIANT form of Lorentz Force ?

Comment: Yes.  There are quite a few more steps.  It ends up being somewhat complicated, but yes, there is relationship between the 4-potential and the 4-current that is covariant under lorentz transformations.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Ok, I will study in this context. Thanks for your time and guidance.

Comment: Check sections 3A and 4D of following article. But warning: Stack Exchange moderators and your school teachers may not approve of this work.
Periodic relativity: the theory of gravity in flat space time
https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.4539v11